# Git troubles when adding second homestead site

Tags: git, homestead

The beauty of Homestead (as I understand it) is being able to have multiple sites, and I'm trying to get that working, git-wise. I've been up and running with Homestead for one laravel project for a while, and I've just added a second project- it's a small, simple php website, called nptest. Everything went fine adding it in Homestead.yaml and my hosts file, and I can see it locally in the browser- hooray!

Now onto git!

I made a new repo in github (nptest4).  For context, my local directory structure is ...\Github\Homestead\, with children directories for my laravel project for new project ("nptest")

1. In nptest, I made a new branch called master-nptest including just the new stuff (because my existing master branch has stuff from my laravel project)
2. I used git ls-tree to confirm that master-nptest has only these nptest files
3. from that nptest folder I ran the usual commands suggested by github to make my first commit:

   git remote add origin-nptest4 https://github.com/dianekaplan/nptest4.git

   git push -u origin-nptest4 master-nptest

**The problem:** When I look at the nptest4 repo in github, it's got not only my new stuff but also the old Laravel files :(

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry- newbie question: it turned out I needed to do 'git init' in my new directory (for the original progress I think git init was done in the Homestead folder overall, and that was still 'in effect').  I did that, repeated my steps fresh, and now my new repo has only the new stuff